# Magento 1 - Why is the default Contact Us path "/contacts"?

Tags: magento

Curious as to why a vanilla install of Magento 1 contact us page has the path "/contacts", I thought it was a misspelling, but there could be another reason?

Comment: No reason really. `Mage_Contacts` is also one of the few modules which name is in plural form. Annoying...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 1 the reason is because the configuration says so, if you take a look to the config.xml in the `Mage/Contacts/etc` folder you will see something like this:

```
<routers>
    <contacts>
       <use>standard</use>
        <args>
            <module>Mage_Contacts</module>
            <frontName>contacts</frontName>
        </args>
    </contacts>
</routers>
```

That specifies the path the **contactsIndex** method will be resolving to.

You can off course, change this by creating your own module or use a redirect instead, you can find the document